# Flutter error : The constructor being called isn't a const constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-development

I'm working on my first Flutter project, I'm building a Login page, I created a variable to store a TextFormFieldController but I got the error above because I deleted the constructor.
When I return this constructor I cant declare a global variable to store the TextFormFieldController.

this is my code : (the Login page) :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  var loginUsernameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const Edge

Insets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text(
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email Address",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
    

    TextFormField(
              controller: TextEditingController(),
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  "LOGIN",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the main.dart (Where I got the error) :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'login_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to remove const before **MaterialApp** :

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
```

Comment: It works thank you man! can you explain me what is the relationship between removing the const keyword and the error please ?

Comment: const keyword requires hard coded constant value but you are building dynamic widget which is not constant that's why it's throwing an error. Also please mark as answered if it worked. Thanks

Comment: it's actualy works I haven't notice the const before Materials set me into problems

Answer (score 1):

If you create `const` constructor for `LoginScreen` widget, that will resolve the `MyApp` issue. But the next issue comes from `var loginUsernameController = TextEditingController();` while now we have created  `const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);`

For `const` constructor class, it requires `final` variables inside class level.

But `TextEditingController()` itself is a `non-const` constructor.

You can also initialize `loginUsernameController` inside `build` method while it is `StatelessWidget` and for `StatefulWidget` use `initState`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I have understand thank you a lot.

Comment: I have a question, I did what @Diwyansh said in the previous answer! is that the best practise ? (Removing the const keyword from the MaterialApp)... or the best is to create the variable inside the build method ?

Comment: It is recommended to use `const` when ever possible, it would be issue placing inside build if it was `statefullWidget`, but for cases like this, you like to pass through constructor